# Tilemill MBTiles SQLite database schema

Tags: tilemill, sqlite, mbtiles, cartocss

I'm trying to resolve the inability to load a raster MBTiles map on a GPS that added support for the format.

Maps created using QGIS or CalTopo will work. The SQLite database only contains two tables-tiles and metadata. There are no indices or views.

Maps created using Tilemill won't work. The SQLite database has 6 tables, 6 indices and 3 views (one of which are the tiles).  Some of the additional objects are use for the interactivity layer supported by Tilemill.

I suspect that differences in the database schema are the source of the incompatibility.

Is there any way to make Tilemill generate an MBTiles file in the using the two table database schema?

Is there any way to convert MBTiles schemas?

Are there any other methods to render MBTiles files from ESRI and CartoCSS?